# C++ CopyFile() does not works on c:\

Tags: c++, winapi

hello guys i have one simple program which copying itself. Its work great when i copying in D disk. But when im trying to copy it on c disk nothing happens.

This is code :

```
int main()
{
        string appDir = "";
        appDir = std::string( result, GetModuleFileName( NULL, result, MAX_PATH ) );
    CopyFile(appDir.c_str(), "C:\\SelfCopyingApp.exe", 1);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks...

Comment: Are you running as administrator? Which version of Windows? Ugh, `system("PAUSE");`

Comment: Check the return value and `GetLastError`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the system drive has locked down permissions which prevent anyone from copying things there who are not administrators. Generally, one should not be messing with the root of the drive. If you need to do something like an installer, then you should

1. Ask for Admin rights
2. Install yourself in the correct location, namely `%PROGRAMFILES%\CompanyName\ProductName`

Messing with the root of the drive is asking for trouble; that's not where programs go.

Other notes on this code not related to your question:

1. `system("pause")` is wrong. Use `std::cin.get()` if you really want a portable way to get that behavior.
2. You should probably be using Unicode.
3. If `GetModuleFileName` fails you're going to be copying some random garbage to that location, not yourself. You need to check the return codes and `GetLastError` codes of every Win32 function.

Comment: About #1: He's using the win32 API, why the hell would he care if `system("pause")` was portable or not? But #2 is certainly true - CopyFile expects a `LPCTSTR` which is probably a wide string with default settings.

Comment: @Voo: 1. Because it's nasty and doesn't really do what the programmer expects. Starting another process and setting up a wait loop just to wait for the user to press a key is stupid and wasteful. Sure, he's using the Win32 API today, but that's no reason to set someone up for bad habits tomorrow. 2. Obviously (s)he has not defined `UNICODE` because `CopyFile` is compiling when passed a narrow string.